ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1200: <line 16, column 46> mismatched input ',' expecting LEFT_PAREN
grunt> joined_data = JOIN filtered_features BY (store, date), sales BY (store, date);
2024-04-02 13:19:05,110 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1200: <line 16, column 46>  mismatched input ',' expecting LEFT_PAREN
Details at logfile: /home/vboxuser/Documents/DDPC/EX9/q2/2/pig_1712044037517.log
Pig Stack Trace

ERROR 1200: <line 16, column 46>  mismatched input ',' expecting LEFT_PAREN
Failed to parse: <line 16, column 46>  mismatched input ',' expecting LEFT_PAREN
at org.apache.pig.parser.QueryParserDriver.parse(QueryParserDriver.java:244)

at org.apache.pig.parser.QueryParserDriver.parse(QueryParserDriver.java:182)

at org.apache.pig.PigServer$Graph.validateQuery(PigServer.java:1792)

at org.apache.pig.PigServer$Graph.registerQuery(PigServer.java:1765)

at org.apache.pig.PigServer.registerQuery(PigServer.java:708)

at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.processPig(GruntParser.java:1110)

at org.apache.pig.tools.pigscript.parser.PigScriptParser.parse(PigScriptParser.java:512)

at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:230)

at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:205)

at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt.run(Grunt.java:66)

at org.apache.pig.Main.run(Main.java:564)

at org.apache.pig.Main.main(Main.java:175)

at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)

at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)

at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:244)

at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:158)

================================================================================
There is a paranthesis but still error Left Paran

The docs seem to include quotes around the parenthesis. Try BY '('store, date')'.

it worked if i mentioned the column number
grunt> joined_data = JOIN filtered_features BY ($0, $2), sales BY ($0, $1);
